# How can I create a csv file for my few of the large records present in my database

Tags: oracle, export-to-csv

I have 200 000 records in oracle database. I want to create a csv file for 100 000 records which is present in my table. How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use sql developer
Tools menu -> Database Export will do